# Removing the spacing between the Header and Nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to build my site for my own web design company. It's kind of ironic that I'm doing that considering I'm asking a basic question. On the other hand I'm only building basic sites to gain experience. My problem is that I'm trying to remove the gap between the header and navigation bar. I tried to set them both to fixed positions, then set the "top" values, but when the browser window is re-sized everything is out of place. It needs to be responsive and viewed on mobile and desktop devices.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Picasso</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styling.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <img src="img/pwd_logo_05.png" alt="logo" id="logo">
            <h2>For Desktop &amp; Mobile </h2>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Donate</li>
                <li>Request</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
                <li>Home</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</html>
```

css

```
header {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}

#logo {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 1.5em;
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
}

h2 {
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;

}

li {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    padding: .875em 1em;
    color: whitesmoke;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
    background-image:url(img/background.png);
}
```

Comment: try this css that removes the default padding and margin from the list : `nav > ul {margin:0; padding: 0;}`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `padding-bottom: 1em;` from your `h2` css, and the `padding: .875em 1em;` from your `li` css.

Padding will essentially reserve space around the element, resulting in the gap you see now. Removing the padding from the css will remove the space.

What I've suggested will answer your question but might not be the best solution - you'll want to learn a bit about padding, and then change your css so that the padding is applied in the right places and avoided in the wrong ones.

Comment: I tried both, but no resolve. I thought padding applies to the inside of the container, and margin was what creates the space outside of the container.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the margin set to your title H2.
Try to set "margin-bottom" of it to 0.

Same thing for the "margin-top" of the UL element.

Comment: 0 didn't work, so I tried a negative value, that solved the issue

Comment: Hmm. 0 should work; try 0px instead but maybe there is something else in your whole code that interfere withe it ? Ps : don't put negative number if you don't find the issue and don't understand why it does that when you put 0. If you want to test in live please use inspector (right click > inspect) : it shows you exactly what causes spacing between elements. There is plenty of tutorials on the web to help you use these useful tools ;D